# I can't get the multinode tree picker from umbraco 4.8

Tags: xml, loops, razor, umbraco

I' ve got this XML struct:

```
<tagging>
      <MultiNodePicker>
          <nodeId>119683</nodeId>
          <nodeId>119684</nodeId>
      </MultiNodePicker>
  </tagging>

@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits DynamicNodeContext
@
{
    <ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.tagging)
    {
        var node = Library.NodeById(item.InnerText);
        if (node.Id != 0)
        {
            <li>@node.Name></li>
        }
    }
    </ul>
}
```

but doesn't work, maybe I have written something wrong.

Anyone?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you probably need to change your code to something like this:

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits DynamicNodeContext
@
{
    <ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Tagging.MultiNodePicker)
    {
        var node = Library.NodeById(item.InnerText);
        if (node.Id != 0)
        {
            <li>@node.Name></li>
        }
    }
    </ul>
}
```

You may find it a lot easier to configure the MultiNodePicker to save the nodes as a comma separated list instead of xml - then you could just do this:

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits DynamicNodeContext
@
{
    <ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Tagging)
    {
        var node = Library.NodeById(item);
        if (node.Id != 0)
        {
            <li>@node.Name></li>
        }
    }
    </ul>
}
```

If there's no other reason to store the nodes as XML then this is probably the simplest way.